# Request.Response object doesn't redirect to the right URL

Tags: python, redirect, mechanize, mechanicalsoup

2 months old Python noob here,

I'm using MechanicalSoup to fill in a login form on a webpage, which i then want to submit and go to the user-profile page.

Altough i don't get any errors in my code, after submitting the form, i still get the current url of the homepage from my new response object. 
Moreover, the status code of this repsonse object is 200, which implies that the request has been succesful?

here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def randomstring():
     letters = string.ascii_lowercase
     return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(5))



br = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser(soup_config=({'features': 'html.parser'}))
browser = br.open("https://www.opinieland.nl/nl-nl")
page = br.get_current_page()

Form = br.select_form(nr=0)
form = br.get_current_form()

for tag in page.find_all(True):
   LOGIN = page.select('input[class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-6 form-control"]')
   for i in LOGIN:
       if i.get("name") == None:
         i["name"] = randomstring()
       else:
         continue

apsuser = Form.form.select('input[class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-6 form-    control"]')[0]
apspas = Form.form.select('input[class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-6 form-     control"]')[1]

form.set_input({apsuser.get('name'): username, apspas.get('name'): password})
form2 = br.select_form(selector=('a[class="btn btn-danger"]'))
soup = br.submit(form2, url="https://www.opinieland.nl/nl-nl")
```

As is said, there code won't show up any errors. and when launching the browser, i can see that the forms are filled in correctly

help is appreciated :), any additional tips about my code too ofcourse!

Comment: server may not like you and not login you and redirect to main page with status 200. And you will not get error because code can be correct.

Comment: so the server knows that the user-agent of this request isn't a human or something?? and therefore rejects the request?

Comment: mostly servers check only user-agent but some may have hidden fields in form or run JavaScript to check user.

Comment: ah okay, is there anyway to go around this 'block'/ban and login?

Comment: python with `Selenium` can control browser and it will work as natural as normal human. Or you have to investigate what's going on when you login and try to do exactly the same with current code - `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

MechanicalSoup is capable of submitting a login form, so long as it is not handled by JavaScript (see ["When to use MechanicalSoup?"](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#when-to-use-mechanicalsoup)). In this case, I think a minor misuse of MechanicalSoup is causing the error.

- Once you fill out the form, you generally want to submit it with `br.submit_selected()`.
- The variable `form2` does not appear to be a form (no POST or GET action), just a link:

  ```
  In [9]: form2.form
  Out[9]: <a class="btn btn-danger" id="apslogin" style="margin-top:4px"> Inloggen</a>
  ```

To submit the correct form, you should therefore replace

```
form2 = br.select_form(selector=('a[class="btn btn-danger"]'))
soup = br.submit(form2, url="https://www.opinieland.nl/nl-nl")
```

with

```
br.submit_selected()
```

For a complete example that showcases filling out and submitting a login form, see the [MechanicalSoup login tutorial](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#a-more-complete-example-logging-in-into-github).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i still get the Original mainpage url after usinng br.submit_selected()

Comment: is there a way to combine Selenium and mechincalsoup to do this? When i use Selenium with this the log-in process works, but i rather use mechanicalsoup for filling in forms

Comment: No, MechanicalSoup is just a simple library on top of requests and BeautifulSoup, we have no plan to extend it to support Selenium.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I answered a bit too quickly: there may be a way to use Selenium, then get the cookiejar and inject it to a MechanicalSoup browser object.